# Specify String Lenth in Awk Pattern Search

Tags: awk

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Given a test.log of:

```
123.123.123.123 321.321.321.321 GET /test1234/asdfasdfpioasdfjkhweris,9
123.123.123.123 321.321.321.321 GET /4321test/asdfasdfpioasdfjkhweris,9
123.123.123.123 321.321.321.321 GET /test123456/asdfasdfpioasdfjkhweris,9
```

I am trying to isolate the first two by specifying the number of characters between the / and /.

This works

```
cat test* | awk '{if($4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\//) print $0}'
```

But this does not

```
cat test* | awk '{if($4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}\//) print $0}'
```

What am I missing?

I've also tried:

```
cat test* | awk '$4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\// {print $0}'
```

which didn't work either.

UPDATE:
I also tried the same commands using gawk, which is also available for me to use, and they still didn't work.

Comment: Is your awk implementation provided by `mawk`? It looks like `mawk` doesn't support the `{m,n}` syntax at all. Try using a more full featured implementation like GNU's `gawk`.

Comment: @jw013 gawk is also on this machine.  Will the same string work with gawk?

Comment: It should, but why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: I did, and it isn't working.  I will update my main post.

Comment: The two `awk` commands work for me (with GNU `awk` 4.x). (Older `awk`s may not have supported the brace quantifiers.) - Unrelated, but BTW, you should omit the `cat` and let `awk` open the files: `awk ' ... ' test*`.

Comment: @Janis Unfortunately the real files I'm going to be using this on are compressed logs (*.gz) so usually I write zcat first.  I didn't think that awk could uncompress files.

Comment: Right. That precondition wasn't apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat test* | gawk --re-interval '$4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\// {print $0}'
# OR
cat test* | gawk --re-interval '{if( $4 ~ "^/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}/") {print $0}}'
```

From GNU awk's manpage:

- --re-interval –
            Enable  the  use  of  interval  expressions  in  regular
            expression matching

Re also ensuring that at least on numeric digit is included:

```
gawk --re-interval '$4 ~ "^/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}/" &&
                    $4 ~ "^/[^/]{0,7}[0-9]" {print $0}'
```

Comment: Which should of course be equivalent to the non-imperative "awk'ish" form: `awk --re-interval '$4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\//'`

Comment: @Janis or Peter.O Now how could I ensure there was at least one number in that 8 character string?

Comment: I'd try (untested): `awk --re-interval '$4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\// && substr($4,2,8) ~ /[0-9]/'`.

Comment: awk --re-interval '$4 ~ /^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\// && $4 ~ /^\/.{1,7}[0-9]/' test.log appears to work.  I'll try your example next.

Comment: Well, that's another option. (Maybe a bit more cryptic than the substr() suggestion.) - But as you wrote it it would not match a leading digit; shouldn't that be `{0,7}` according to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24246/discussion-between-user112802-and-janis).

Answer (score 0):

why not try .. ?

```
awk -F/ 'length($2) == 8 '
```

- `-F/` use / as separator
- `length($2)` compute length
- default awk action print it